# Azure AD SSO for native mobile application

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am working on a react-native project. I need to implement single-sign-on on this app. I am using plugin "react-native-azure-ad-2" to implement this. But when I try to sign-on it fails. The error I am getting is  "Application '601...' is not supported for this API version." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you register the app? Azure portal or the new apps.dev.microsoft.com?

Comment: Azure portal- https://portal.azure.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module you mention uses the new v2 endpoints. You have to register the app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com, not portal.azure.com.

Comment: Just to add, [here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare) a nice document on the differences between the v1 and v2 endpoints in Azure AD. tl;dr v1 is for Azure AD accounts and v2 has converged Azure AD and Microsoft Accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One more thing, When I register the react-native app on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ what platform should I choose- should it be web or be native??

Comment: @nexus A react-native should be a native app as it cannot protect a client/app secret.